# Setting up IPv6 routing between subnets

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm sure this is a trivial question for people experienced with network configuration, but I've spent hours trying to get this to work and reading up on IPv6 subnetting and router advertisement mechanisms and I'm still not getting it, so I apologize for that.

This is the topology that I have:

```
  ┌────────┐
  │ Router ├─────┐
  └───┬────┘     │
      │          │
┌─────┴────┐  ┌──┴──────────┐
│ Linux PC │  │ Windows PC  │
└───┬──────┘  └─────────────┘
    │
 ┌──┴─┐
 │ C1 │
 └────┘
```

The Windows and Linux PC are connected to the Router via WiFi (they may even be talking directly to each other - not sure if this is allowed in 802.11xx) while C1 is connected to the Linux PC via an Ethernet cable. I'm trying to set up the Linux PC as a gateway so I can access C1 from the Windows PC without having to touch the router configuration. With IPv4 I managed to achieve this by setting a static IP for the Linux PC on the Ethernet interface and adding a route under Windows that forwards the entire 192.168.0.xx subnet to the Linux PC as a gateway (C1 has a static IP set in the 192.168.0.xx subnet while the router and the devices in this network use the 192.168.1.xx subnet).

Now I'm forced to achieve the same under IPv6 (an application under Windows sends out UDP broadcasts over IPv6 (to FF02::1) and expects to find C1). I set up radvd on the Linux PC with the following configuration:

```
interface wlp0s20f3
{
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  prefix fd00:abcd:1234:1234::/64
  {
    AdvAutonomous on;
    AdvOnLink off;
  };
};
interface enx0c3796559217
{
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  prefix fd00:abcd:1234:1235::/64
  {
    AdvOnLink off;
    AdvAutonomous on;
  };
};
```

I assume that it's better to have different prefixes for the different interfaces? How can I enable discovery of C1 by the Windows PC?

I can ping Linux on its FE80:... address. Looking at it with Wireshark I can also see packets from the Windows PC when I ping Linux under its d00:abcd:1234:1234:... address, although Linux starts immediate neighbor discovery for the pinged address (leading me to think it doesn't consider this address its own), but the pings remain unanswered.
I know about the FF02::1 multicast address, but is there a multicast address for a given subnet? (e.g. d00:abcd:1234:1234:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx where all devices respond that belong in this subnet?)

By the way the Linux PC is running Ubuntu.

Comment: `ff02::1` is a _link local_ multicast address. It won't span multiple subnets. Even if you manage to get your routes working, it won't help you here. You would more likely need to bridge your network between the interfaces on the Linux machine. Or persuade the application to use `ff05::1` (site local multicast) instead.